# Retrieve only one object inside an array elasticsearch

Tags: mapping, elasticsearch

I have an `index` named `books` which has `reviews` as an `object` which can handle arrays.
While retrieving data, in a particular case I only want the `review` having maximum `rating`.

```
"books" :{ 
    "reviews": {
        "properties": {
            "rating": {
                "type": "float"
             },
            "comments": {
                "type": "string"
             }
         }
     },
    "author" : {
        "type" : "string"
    }
 }
```

Many books can have many `reviews` each having some `rating`. For a particular use case I only want the result set to have the `reviews` having maximum `rating`. I need to build a search `query` for that kind of result.

```
POST books/_search
{
    "size": 51,

    "sort": [
   {
      "reviews.rating": {
         "order": "asc",
         "mode" : "min"
      }
   }
],
"fields": [
   "reviews","author"]
}
```

By using `script_fields` one can build dynamic `fields` but not `objects`. Else I could have made a dynamic object `reviews` having one field as `rating` and another as `comment`.

Comment: I do not see a way to accomplish this with statistical facet. I mis-understood your question and thought you just needed the max rating across all books. Therefore, I have deleted my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`script_fields` can be used to build both dynamic fields and objects:

```
curl -XDELETE localhost:9200/test-idx
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/test-idx -d '{
    "mappings": {
        "books" :{ 
            "reviews": {
                "properties": {
                    "rating": {
                        "type": "float"
                     },
                    "comments": {
                        "type": "string"
                     }
                 }
             },
            "author" : {
                "type" : "string"
            }
        }
    }
}'

curl -XPOST "localhost:9200/test-idx/books?refresh=true" -d '{
    "reviews": [{
        "rating": 5.5,
        "comments": "So-so"
    }, {
        "rating": 9.8,
        "comments": "Awesome"
    }, {
        "rating": 1.2,
        "comments": "Awful"
    }],
    "author": "Roversial, Cont"
}'

curl "localhost:9200/test-idx/books/_search?pretty" -d '{
    "fields": ["author"],
    "script_fields": {
        "highest_review": {
            "script": "max_rating = 0.0; max_review = null; for(review : _source[\"reviews\"]) {  if (review.rating > max_rating) { max_review = review; max_rating = review.rating;}} max_review"
        }
    }
}'
```